# What made a person a follower of an ideology?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I'm trying to understand when someone is a follower of an ideology. What aspects classify a person as a follower of an ideology?

Another question: It is possible agree with aspects of an ideology, but not being  follower?

Comment: Hi, welcome to philosophy SE. I don't think you have the right word, "adept of ideology" returns a single search result which misuses "adept", perhaps you mean "adherent". Also, we do not answer questions about definitions of words on this site http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/when-is-a-question-about-definitions see dictionaries:"*Follower often has an implication of personal relationship or of slavish acquiescence. Adherent, a more formal word, has implications of active championship of a person or a point of view.*" http://www.dictionary.com/browse/follower

Comment: See [Ideology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/law-ideology/) : "Ideology today is generally taken to mean not a science of ideas, but the ideas themselves, and moreover ideas of a particular kind. Ideologies are ideas whose purpose is not epistemic, but political. Thus an ideology exists to confirm a certain political viewpoint, serve the interests of certain people, or to perform a functional role in relation to social, economic, political and legal institutions."

Comment: If so, an "adept of an ideology" is mainly a "follower" of a specific political party or viewpoint.

Comment: @Conifold, sorry, you are right.

Comment: @Mauro, imagine an ideology about the best cokie on earth. This ideology says (1) to made a good cokie you have to use some chocolate (2) the best cokie on earth is made with white  chocolate. Now, if i agree with both of the viewpoints, that means i am a follower of this ideology? That means i have to defend this viewpoints? My point is, i understand what made a good (and the best) cokie on earth, but i don't want to raise a flag because of it. I think the only way to do this is agree with some points, but disagree whit at least one, is that right?

Comment: I do not think that "ideology" applies to cookies...

Comment: It's a bad example, sorry. But you understand my point?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  I would flip that over -- there is no ideology that applies *only* to cookies.  Any ideology has to apply to *everything* (including cookies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the strongest sense, an ideology is a specific way of looking at ideas in terms of a chosen motive.  It differs from a mere theory in that it makes ideas fit into it, or rather makes them fit together in terms of itself, instead of trying to fit together with other theories as though they are on par with it.

So prescriptive religions are ideologies, and to a certain degree so are non-prescriptive religions, (the earlier answer's choice of Buddhism is excellent.)  But so are other overarching philosophical constructs like Marxism, psychoanalysis, pacifism, statism, or paradigmatic Science.  If you accept them as presented, they propose a given way of manipulating all other ideas and forming your overall worldview into a structure subsidiary to themselves.

So to your main question -- the question of whether you are following a given ideology is most easily answered by asking what would cause you to consider it irrelevant.  For a follower, the ideology is relevant to any fact or idea even distantly logically connected to it, and the new idea must always be first vetted in terms of the ideology, not the other way around.

To the second point -- yes.  It is easy to take things that are intended to be ideologies and treat them as simple theories, to consider whether they provide a good way of looking at things under certain conditions, but never using them as a guide to your overall process of learning.  This is especially relevant if a number of ideologies impact your life at the same time.

Orthodox religious people throughout history have always done this to sciences; theist scientists often do this to religion; old-fashioned feminists and pacifists subordinate Marxism to their own ideology, but can make extensive use of it as a motivating explanation, and may still do this within a more strictly scientific framing based upon statistical observation.  Things can get as layered as you choose, but if there is intellectual bedrock, you are following an ideology.

Comment: Thank you, it's a really interesting answer. Can you give me some example about this "intellectual bedrock" ?

Comment: "It is easy to take things that are intended to be ideologies and treat them as simple theories, to consider whether they provide a good way of looking at things under certain conditions, but never using them as a guide to your overall process of learning." That was very enlightening, thank you! I would like to see an example, please.

Comment: The whole next paragraph is examples of that.  You can have an ideology like a religion that really prevents you from adopting science itself as an ideology, and still use science as a theory, for what it is good for, accepting its results, but not its worldview.  etc...  Or you can have an ideology like pacifism that contradicts the notion of revolution in Marxism, but still think various Marxisms say some important things about the world that are instrumental to achieving international peace....

Comment: As for 'intellectual bedrock', you know when you hit it.  E.g. I am currently arguing in another thread with someone over whether initiating violence is always wrong, and no argument I make matters -- because they are from a given ethical standard that just does not allow that position to be argued with.  It is not moveable because it is a part of their ideology -- everything has to be moved around to allow for it to remain true.

Comment: I read again and thats true, now is better to understand. Thank you! One last thing, can you indicate some books, websites or videos about the subject?

Comment: I am not much use on that front.  My memory for where my ideas come from is not as good as others here.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As regards agreeing with aspects of an ideology, but not being a follower, in Buddhism there is an ideology that ideology should be abandoned.  That is why Buddhism is called the Gateless Gate.  Once you see it you abandon it (along with other hang-ups).  The Dharma (wisdom) is also likened to a [raft](http://buddhism.about.com/od/sacredbuddhisttexts/fl/The-Buddhas-Raft-Parable.htm) that is abandoned once one has crossed to the further shore.

A couple of example of this self-erasing ideology.

[Paramatthaka Sutta: On Views](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/snp/snp.4.05.irel.html)

> Those skilled (in judgment) say that (a view becomes) a bond if,
>   relying on it, one regards everything else as inferior. ... Abandoning
>   (the views) he had (previously) held and not taking up (another), he
>   does not seek a support even in knowledge. ... That brahmana who does
>   not grasp at a view, with what could he be identified in the world?

[The Vagrakkhedikâ or Diamond-Cutter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/sbe49/sbe4929.htm)

> 'What do you think then, O Subhûti, is there anything which has been
>   known by the Tathâgata in the form of the highest perfect knowledge?'
>   The venerable Subhûti said: 'Not indeed, O Bhagavat, there is nothing,
>   O Bhagavat, that has been known by the Tathâgata in the form of the
>   highest perfect knowledge.' Bhagavat said: 'So it is, Subhûti, so it
>   is. Even the smallest thing is not known or perceived there, therefore
>   it is called the highest perfect knowledge.'